# characterization of points where a min of a map is attained

Tags: geometry

here is my problem.

Consider a triangle $ABC$.
For any point $M$ in the plane, define 
$$f_\infty (M)=\max(MA,MB,MC),$$ $$f_2(M)=\sqrt{MA^2+MB^2+MC^2},$$$$f_1(M)=MA+MB+MC.$$

These maps are continuous for the natural topology so there is at least one minimal value that is inside the triangle (compact subset of the plane). It is easy to see that the min for $f_\infty$ is the circumcenter of the triangle. I'd say that other interesting values correspond to the centroid and the orthocenter. Is it possible to prove this only with elementary tools (not using any scalar product)? Thanks in advance for any hint :)

Comment: I'd say scalar product is quite an elementary tool=)

Comment: $f_1$ is not associated with the orthocenter but with the Fermat-Torricelli-Steiner point.

Comment: The circumcenter of the triangle is inside the triangle it the triangle is acute; not if it is obtuse.

Comment: Well, I am currently preparing some activities for middle-schoolers and I'd like to present how to use some tools in numerical geometry (with geogebra) to make some observations and hypotheses, but of course they know nothing about scalar product so I can't even talk about it.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Michael, I haven't explored enough the problem before. Hmm, concerning the Fermat-Torricelli-Steiner point I should maybe forget it and focus on the first part only.